Check in Dart whether a ChaCha20-Poly1305-IETF decryption was successful
In my Dart/Flutter Code I have data that is encrypted with ChaCha20-Poly1305-IETF.
I decrypt the data using the Pointycastle library and the following code:
Uint8List encryptedData = Uint8List.fromList([...]);
Uint8List nonce = Uint8List.fromList([...]);
Uint8List encryptionKey = Uint8List.fromList([...]);

final ChaCha20Poly1305 chaCha20Poly1305 = ChaCha20Poly1305(ChaCha7539Engine(), Poly1305());
final params = AEADParameters(KeyParameter(encryptionKey), 128, nonce, encryptedData);
chaCha20Poly1305.init(false, params);

decryptedData = chaCha20Poly1305.process(encryptedData); // this can be wrong

I now have the following question: How can I find out whether the decryption was successful? Even if the encryptionKey is obviously wrong (e.g. if I change it hardcoded), decryptedData contains a list of data at the end. This data is of course not correct and causes problems in further processing. I would now like to find out whether the decryption has failed and then simply discard the data.

As far as I can see, ChaCha20Poly1305 does not contain an implementation of process(), so the implementation of the base class BaseAEADCipher  is called, which only executes processBytes(), but no doFinal(). However, the latter is responsible for authentication.

Try the implementation from the PointyCastle tests, which also takes doFinal() into account.

What is "correct" data? Is the data not following an expected pattern/convention or is it simply not the exact data you were expecting? The first step toward checking if the data is correct is letting the program know what correct data even looks like.

@Topaco thank you for the answer. processBytes() + doFinal() worked for me. Will add an answer with updated Code.

With the Solution suggested by @Topaco I came to the following result, which works for me:
    final ChaCha20Poly1305 chaChaEngine = ChaCha20Poly1305(ChaCha7539Engine(), 
    Poly1305());
    final params = AEADParameters(KeyParameter(encryptionKey), 128, nonce, Uint8List(0));
    chaChaEngine.init(false, params);
    
    decrypted = Uint8List(encryptedData.length - encryptionType.macLength);
    int len = chaChaEngine.processBytes(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.length, decrypted, 0);
    try {
        len += chaChaEngine.doFinal(decrypted, len);
    } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Could not decrypt data: $e');
        return null;
    }

